# TSQL: OR Status of Previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm trying to figure out how to only include PPO/PPB tasks in R, D, or C status, if in R or D, only include those done in the previous month.

```
select 
d.Address 'Property Address',
d.Client_id 'Client ID',
t.vendor 'Vendor Name',
t.req_dt 'Date Task Ordered',
t.due_dt 'Date Task Due',
case 
when t.status = 'D' then 'Done'
when  t.status = 'C' then 'Cancel'
when   t.status = 'R' then 'Received'
else ''
End  'Task Status',
t.task_type,
d.portfolio
,am.last AssetManagerLastName
,t.done_dt TaskDoneDate
,e.submitted_dt 'Completed Date'
,DATEDIFF(day,t.req_dt,e.submitted_dt) AS [Days to Complete]
from resnet_mysql..property_details d 
 join resnet_mysql..property_tasks t on t.property_id = d.property_id
left join resnet_mysql..property_exps e on e.property_id = t.property_id and 
e.task_id = t.task_id
left join resnet_mysql.dbo.asset_mgrs AM on AM.am_id=d.am_id
where  d.res_id = 125 and t.task_type in( 'PPB', 'PPO') 
 and 
t.status = ('C')
 OR (
  t.status IN ('R' ,'D') 
     AND
        t.done_dt = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))
order by t.vendor, t.task_type, t.req_dt desc
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`t.done_dt = DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE()))` is currently getting a month from today, which is 3/13, meaning you will miss the rest of the days int he month. If you want the whole month of the previous month, look for the first of last month and the last of last month instead.

```
t.done_dt >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
AND
t.done_dt < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0)
```

The second expression looks for `<` the first of the current month, to ensure we get records like `3/31/2017 23:59:59`

```
where  
    (d.res_id = 125 and t.task_type in( 'PPB', 'PPO'))
    and
    (t.status = ('C') OR (
                        t.status IN ('R' ,'D') 
                         AND
                        t.done_dt >= DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
                         AND
                         t.done_dt < DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, 0)
                        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks this date does work but now For some reason I can't seem to get all 3 statuses in the query though. It is only giving me the 'D' status.

Comment: @leeTey it's a parentheses grouping i suspect... see my edit.

Comment: Interesting @leeTey. I just tried another grouping which should work.

Comment: @leeTey, check your data... my tests seem to work (http://rextester.com/PAFSL70251)

Comment: No worries @leeTey, let us know (with sample data and expected output) if you think the condition still isn't being met yet. Try removing the res_id = 125 too perhaps. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Filter with an `or` condition in the where clause. Note the sql below is for exemplification purposes rename as appropriate.

```
SELECT * 
    FROM TABLE
    WHERE task_type IN ('PPO', 'PPB')
        AND 
        ( 
            task ='C' 
                OR
            ( task IN ('R','D') AND [Date Task Ordered] BETWEEN CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -( DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2)) ), DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 1)))
            AND CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(d, -( DAY(GETDATE()) ), GETDATE())) )
        )
```